# Does appharbor always build solution using 'Release' build config?

Tags: appharbor

Does appharbor always build solution using 'Release' build config ? Can I make appharbor to build my apps using certain configuration, e.g. 'Release-for-appharbor' ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AppHarbor always builds your code in `Release` configuration. You can find additional resources on how [AppHarbor recommends you manage environments](http://support.appharbor.com/kb/getting-started/managing-environments).

We'd love to have your suggestions on how to improve this, you can add feedback on the [feedback forum](https://appharbor.com/feedback).

Comment: So then it's not possible to use apphb to host a test environment having a separate build + web.config transformation?

Comment: Nope, that's not currently supported.

Answer (score 0):

To execute the build process locally in the same fashion as AppHarbor

From the Visual Studio Command Prompt

`msbuild solution.sln /p:Configuration=Release /property:OutDir=C:\temp`